# Visual Studio IntelliSense - change method creation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

First off all, sorry if this question already exist but my english is limited for this task.

I use Visual Studio on C# and of course, IntelliSense.

When I write a new method, an If or any other "method/constructor", IntelliSense write like that (when I press Tab or Enter to validate the suggestion)

Actual result :

```
if (true)
{
    // code
}

private void Test()
{
    // code
}
// ...
```

What I want :

```
if (true) {
    // code
}

private void Test() {
    // code
}
// etc. ...
```

See what I want to do ?
I prefer the second 'theme', most readable for me and row economizer.

Is an option behind, hidden in the dark side of VS to do that ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you're asking for javascript style formatting here. I found [this link](http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2009/10/yes-you-can-have-your-javascript-style.html) that might help.

> 1.Click Tools | Options…
>
> 2.Scroll down to the Text Editor node
>
> 3.Expand the C# node
>
> 4.Expand the Formatting node
>
> 5.Click on the New Lines node
>
> 6.You will see a list of options like in the image below which give you full control over when Visual Studio should put your open brace on
> a new line

Answer (score 1):

You can set that on `Options` window:

> Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting -> New Lines